# Build AWS Amplify Backend Using AWS CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code

**;TLDR**: Effectively, how to build a backend for Amplify via AWS CDK which consists of an API Gateway and Lambda function.

I am currently attempting to make an Amplify solution as IaC. The application is relatively simple and only uses Amplify, which hosts frontend and acts as a passthrough the to other resources via the amplify library for JS, API Gateway and a Lambda function. The API Gateway passes REST requests to the Lambda function for processing.

As a dummy app, I have created IaC as such:

```
class AmplifyInfraStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        amplify_app = amplify.CfnApp(self, "MyApp", name='MyAppName')

        lambda_function = lambda_.Function(
               self, 
               'MyFunction', 
               code=lambda_.InlineCode(inline_code),
               handler='index.lambda_handler', 
               runtime=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9
           )

        api = apiGateway.LambdaRestApi(self, 'MyAPI', handler=lambda_function)
```

Which will create all of the resources I require, with the API Gateway and Lambda function being linked; however, the Amplify resource is effectively on its own and does not recognise the other resources linked resources, like in the backend section of the Amplify  AWS Console where it should show 'APIs' and 'Functions'.

I understand this is because I haven't explicitly told them that they should be linked, though reading through the documentation I can't seem to find a way to actually tell Amplify that these resources need to be linked, like I have done for the API Gateway and Lambda in the example above.

My question is, is there a way to use CDK to generate Amplify with a backend containing Functions and APIs? My need for this, as described earlier is so the 'aws-amplify' library in the JS frontend can recognise the linked API to the Amplify resource it's hosted on.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/deploying-a-static-website-with-aws-amplify-and-cdk/) what you are looking for? You can build AWS Amplify with the CDK.

Comment: @Luke Not quite, that effectively gets to where the example code is but only with an Amplify resource. What I'm trying to do is to have Amplify be aware of the other two resources via CDK, so they would show up in the Amplify console like as if you ran 'Amplify deploy' via CLI in an Amplify application.

Comment: You can add [custom resources](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/custom/cdk/) with Amplify using the CDK. **Edit:** I don't think AWS Amplify with build AWS Custom Lambda functions via this solution actually.

Comment: How about creating a CI/CD pipeline, that builds AWS Amplify resources and triggers building the CDK resources too?

Comment: When I push my code commit, AWS Amplify triggers and it builds that environment. A custom CI/CD can be build that listens to the event of the Code Commit repository, and build and synth the CDK resources.

Comment: @Luke I believe it would still run into the issue of Amplify not recognising the resources in its backend environment, as the additional resources would be create via CDK still. Yes the resources would update on the trigger, but I don't think they would be linked

Comment: What resources are you trying to build? Are you outside the native AWS Amplify resources? The custom resources URL is probably your best bet. You build on the CDK, and deploy with AWS Amplify for resources outside the AWS Amplify supported resources.

Comment: @Luke All resources are native to Amplify. Like I described, the complete system is effectively a JS webapp based on Amplify, an API Gateway, and a lambda function, all of which are integrated with the Amplify CLI package.